# Postgresql Insert in multiple table using WITH and Ignore erros

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

My background is MySQL and I am learning PostgreSQL (version 12). I use Python 3.7 and Psycopg2 to send my queries to the database.
I am trying to insert data into multiple table in a "cascade" way. In the bellow example,                 security_id is the primary key used for relationship between mother d_security_id and child d_security_ticker tables, and company_name column in mother table is Non duplicate

```
WITH first_insert AS
        (
            INSERT INTO d_security_id
            (

                company_name
            )
            VALUES 
            (
            %s
            )
            ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
            RETURNING security_id
        )
INSERT INTO d_security_ticker 
        (
            ticker,
            security_id
        )
    VALUES 
        (
            %s, (SELECT security_id FROM first_insert)
        )    
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

When inserting a duplicate company_name, it triggers an error which is handled as expected by ON CONFLICT. It hence, return a None value for security_id (as expected). This then triggers and error on my second insert statement since security_id can not be Null (defined as a foreign key but not explictly defined as NOT NULL fyi in case this matters).
Error received from python script is:

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "security_id" violates not-null constraint
```

What is the correct way to write this simple insert query equivalent to IGNORE in MYSQl
Tx and best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the second insert to this?

```
INSERT INTO d_security_ticker (ticker, security_id )
    SELECT %s, fi.security_id
    FROM first_insert fi
    WHERE fi.security_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the query to this it doesn't throw an error on repeated insert attempts.

```
WITH first_insert AS (
        INSERT INTO d_security_id
        (company_name)
        VALUES ('the name')
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
        RETURNING company_name, security_id
)
INSERT INTO d_security_ticker (ticker, security_id) (SELECT company_name, security_id FROM first_insert)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

This way you only need to replace the value parameter once. The select statement returns no rows when the entry exists, so there is no second insert attempt after the `with` statement.